# New bid is not updating to show the Users input (amount) Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Trying to create an e-bay like platform where users can select an item and bid on it, the bid amount should update to the latest valid bid inputted by a user.

Currently, the amount is not updating to show that a user has made bid, it shows me the pop up message of

```
                messages.success(request, 'Successfully added your bid')
```

but does not update this part of the bids showing or the count increasing

```
 <p>Current price: ${{ detail.current_bid }}</p>
```

Could you please give me an insight of what is causing this?

MODELS.PY

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField()
    current_bid = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    image_url = models.URLField(verbose_name="URL", max_length=255, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, max_length=12, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"(self.title)"

    def no_of_bids(self):
        return self.bidding.all().count()
    
    def current_price(self):
        if self.no_of_bids() > 0:
            return self.bidding.aggregate(Max('new_bid'))['new_bid__max']
        else: 
            return self.current_bid

    def current_winner(self):
        if self.no_of_bids() > 0: 
            return self.bidding.get(new_bid=self.current_price()).user
        else: 
            return None

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

class Bids(models.Model):
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bidding', null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='bidding')
    new_bid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    done_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.new_bid)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['auction', '-new_bid']
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def listing_detail(request, listing_id):
    try:
        detail = get_object_or_404(Auction, pk=listing_id)
    except Auction.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, "This is not available") 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))

    bid_count = Bids.objects.filter(auction=listing_id).count()
    bid_form= BidForm()     

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.auction = detail
            new_comment.save()

            return redirect('listing_detail', listing_id=listing_id)

        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    context = {'detail': detail,
                'bid_count': bid_count, 
                'bid_form': bid_form,
                'comment_form': comment_form
                } 

    return render(request, 'auctions/details.html', context)

@login_required
def make_bid(request, listing_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        auction = Auction.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
        bid_form = BidForm(request.POST)
        if bid_form.is_valid():
            bid_form.instance.user = request.user
            bid_form.instance.item = auction

            if bid_form.instance.new_bid > auction.current_price():
                bid_form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Successfully added your bid')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing_detail", args=(listing_id,)))
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Bid price lower than current price, increase bid please')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing_detail", args=(listing_id,)))


        else:
            context = {
                'bid_form': bid_form
                }
            
            return render(request, 'auctions/details.html', context)  
                
    return render(request, 'auctions/details.html', {'bid_form': bid_form})
```

FORMS.PY

```
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Bids
        fields = ['new_bid']
        labels = {
            'new_bid': ('Bid'),
        }
```

DETAILS.PY

```
                            <p>Current price: ${{ detail.current_bid }}</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p>{{ detail.no_of_bids }} bids so far</p>
                            <hr>

                            <form action="{% url 'make_bid' detail.id %}" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {{ bid_form }}
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-3" value="Place bid">
                            </form>
```

URL.PY

```
    path("make_bid/<int:listing_id>", views.make_bid, name="make_bid"),
```

Comment: I don't see any `detail` variable passed to the template context. Where does `detail` come from?

Comment: I've added the views that the detail comes from